# MySQL sql syntax error LIKE statement and conditionals

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax-error

Perhaps a fresh set of eyes could help me with this.  I thought this error corresponded to the AND OR statements but I switched things around and Still recieved the same error.  Does someone see what is wrong with the following statement? Thank you.  The query works fine without the like clauses.

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '%castillo% OR p.city LIKE %castillo% OR p.country LIKE
>   %castillo% ) GROUP BY ima' at line 1
>
> SELECT p.id, p.name, p.city, p.country, images.name as image,
>   MIN(images.position) as position FROM properties as p, property_images
>   as images WHERE p.id = \images.property_id AND p.is_active = 1
>   AND ( p.name LIKE %castillo% OR p.city LIKE %castillo% OR p.country
>   LIKE %castillo% ) GROUP BY images.property_id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting some quotes around your string literals, e.g.

```
SELECT p.id, p.name, p.city, p.country, images.name as image, MIN(images.position) as position 
FROM properties as p, property_images as images
WHERE p.id = images.property_id 
  AND is_active = 1 
  AND ( p.name LIKE '%castillo%' OR p.city LIKE '%castillo%' OR p.country LIKE '%castillo%' ) 
GROUP BY images.property_id
```